# Spring Integration WS Gateway with Empty Response

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, spring-integration

I am using the "ws:outbound-gateway" with the following attributes,

```
ignore-empty-responses="false" reply-channel="processReplyChannel"
```

i also tried the

```
ignore-empty-responses="FALSE" reply-channel="processReplyChannel"
```

in fact the WS Reply is empty as follows,

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body />
</soap:Envelope>
```

my problem is that channel has a ServiceActivator that will do something in case of a non soap-fault reply message. But it seems that maybe something is missing because the ws processing are never reaching the "processReplyChannel", does  anyone have a  hint on how to process a sucessfull WS call without a response body?

Updating with a sample config.

```
<int:chain input-channel="inputChainChannel"   id="chainId">
        <int:transformer id="firsttransformer"
            ref="firsttransformer" ></int:transformer>
        <int:transformer ref="beanTramsformer" method="someMethod"></int:transformer>
        <int:transformer id="sencondMarshallingTransfomer" ref="sencondMarshallingTransfomer"></int:transformer>
        <int:object-to-string-transformer></int:object-to-string-transformer>
        <ws:header-enricher>
            <ws:soap-action value="theSoapAction" />
        </ws:header-enricher>
        <ws:outbound-gateway 
            uri="${wsEndpoint}"
            interceptor="anInterceptor" ignore-empty-responses="false" reply-channel="processReplyChannel">
            <ws:request-handler-advice-chain>
                    <ref bean="retryAdvice" />
            </ws:request-handler-advice-chain>  
        </ws:outbound-gateway>  
    </int:chain>
```

Regards,

Comment: This might be due to a change in one of the underlying libraries; in the debugger, I see null being returned for an empty body instead of an empty `String`. Investigating...

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug; I opened a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3875) which you can watch.

Comment: Hi Gary, The problem seems to be a little bit more complex.. I made another test changing the EndPoint to return a message (in fact the WS will return the same message that was sent!), and the reply channel was not called. now i dont know if the "reply channel" can be used inside a chain. when i moved the reply channel to the output channel (chain output channel) everything worked fine.

Comment: That is correct; you can't put a `reply-channel` within the chain; the reply goes to the next element in the chain, or the chain's `output-channel` if the gateway is the last element.